# Moving music between iTunes librares

Tags: itunes

I want to create a separate library for Christmas music that is not on my main iTunes library. The plan is to wipe my iPod of regular music and replace it with Christmas music just for the season, then wipe it again and return to normal music. Any ideas?

Comment: Would be a whole lot easier to just create an xmas playlist & select only that to sync from iTunes; then swap back toy your regular sync in a couple of weeks.

Comment: If one of the below answers has solved your issue, please mark it as the correct answer to move it out of the "Unanswered" section. If your issue hasn't been solved, please provide more information about what happened when you tried the below answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create a second iTunes library when you launch iTunes by holding Option (on a Mac) or Shift (on Windows). This allows you to specify a file name and location for the new library which you can populate with whatever media you like. When you want to switch back to your regular library, just hold down the appropriate key again when relaunching iTunes and select the original library file.